# Regex option "Multiline"

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex to match date format with comma.

> yyyy/mm/dd or yyyy/mm

For example:

> 2016/09/02,2016/08,2016/09/30

My code:

```
string data="21535300/11/11\n";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(20\d{2}/(0[1-9]|1[012])(/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30|31))?,?)*$", 
                      RegexOptions.Multiline);

if (!reg.IsMatch(data))
    "Error".Dump();
else
    "True".Dump();
```

I use option multiline.
If string data have "\n".
Any character will match this regex.

For example:

```
string data="test\n"
string data="2100/1/1"
```

[I find option definition in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Multiline). It says:

> It changes the interpretation of the ^ and $ language elements so that they match the beginning and end of a line, instead of the beginning and end of the input string.

I didn't understand why this problem has happened.
Anyone can explan it?
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly because your regex is a group is 0 or more

Comment: Yes, the regex matches an empty *line*.

Comment: Thanks . I understand soon after your explanation.

Comment: BTW, the `string data="2100\1\1"` is incorrect example. *Unrecognized escape sequence `\1'*

Comment: Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex can match an empty line that you get once you add a newline at the end of the string. `"test\n"` contains 2 lines, and the second one gets matched.

See your regex pattern in a free-spacing mode:

```
^                 # Matches the start of a line
 (                # Start of Group 1
   20\d{2}/
   (0[1-9]|1[012])
   (/
     (0[1-9]|[12]\d|30|31)
   )?,?
 )*                # End of group 1 - * quantifier makes it match 0+ times
$                  # End of line
```

If you do not want it to match an empty line, replace the last `)*` with `)+`.

An alternative is to use a more unrolled pattern like

```
^20\d{2}/(0[1-9]|1[012])(/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?(,20\d{2}/(0[1-9]|1[012])(/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?)*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E20%5Cd%7B2%7D%2F(0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D)(%2F(0%5B1-9%5D%7C%5B12%5D%5Cd%7C3%5B01%5D))%3F(%2C20%5Cd%7B2%7D%2F(0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D)(%2F(0%5B1-9%5D%7C%5B12%5D%5Cd%7C3%5B01%5D))%3F)*%24&i=2016%2F09%2F02%2C2016%2F08%2C2016%2F09%2F30&o=nm). Inside the code, it is advisable to use a block and build the pattern dynamically:

```
string date = @"20\d{2}/(0[1-9]|1[012])(/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?";
Regex reg = new Regex(string.Format("^{0}(,{0})*$", date), RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

As you can see, the first block (after the start of the line `^` anchor) is *obligatory* here, and thus an empty line will never get matched.